# Facebook API: Update Group Description

Tags: facebook, facebook-group

Does anyone know how to update Facebook Group information using the API?

I want to push some information to the facebook group (if the admin is logged in to my site).

Answer (score 2):

Nope, this is at the moment of this writting not possible.
See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/#publishing-methods

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that is possible. There aren't many operations available for managing groups through the API (according to the Wiki). Check out the API documentation at this url:
[Facebook API Wiki](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/API)

I'm not sure if you can do anything else than selecting using the FQL though. You can check that out as well (it's on the wiki site).

Comment: Aye, Seems a bit of a pain though! 
Photos and events seem to be covered so why not Groups/Pages?

Comment: Not sure why. I haven't tried using that myself but it's logical that Facebook doesn't want apps to be able to control groups/pages. Do you know of any apps that are able to do so?